# Pointers in C# to make int array?

Tags: c#, c++, c, pointers

The following C++ program compiles and runs as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int* test = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            test[i] = i * 10;

    printf("%d \n", test[5]); // 50
    printf("%d \n", 5[test]); // 50

    return getchar();
}
```

The closest C# simple example I could make for this question is:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    unsafe static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        // error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'int*'
        int* test = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            test[i] = i * 10;

        Console.WriteLine(test[5]); // 50
        Console.WriteLine(5[test]); // Error

        return (int)Console.ReadKey().Key;
    }
}
```

So how do I make the pointer?

Comment: ask yourself why you want to manipulate pointers directly in a managed language.

Comment: Because I'm bored :D

Comment: Alleviate your boredom by reading chapter 18 of the specification -- twice -- before you attempt to write unsafe code in C#.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

C# is not C++ - don't expect the same things to work in C# that worked in C++.  It's a different language, with some inspiration in the syntax.

In C++, array access is a short hand for pointer manipulation.  That's why the following are the same:

```
test[5]
*(test+5)
*(5+test)
5[test]
```

However, this is not true in C#.  `5[test]` is not valid C#, since there is no indexer property on System.Int32.

In C#, you very rarely want to deal with pointers.  You're better off just treating it as an int array directly:

```
int[] test = new int[10];
```

If you really do want to deal with pointer math for some reason, you need to flag your method [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx), and put it into an [fixed context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21(VS.80).aspx).  This would not be typical in C#, and is really probably something completely unnecessary.

If you really want to make this work, the closest you can do in C# would be:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    unsafe static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        fixed (int* test = new int[10])
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                test[i] = i * 10;

            Console.WriteLine(test[5]); // 50
            Console.WriteLine(*(5+test)); // Works with this syntax
        }

        return (int)Console.ReadKey().Key;
    }
}
```

(Again, this is really weird C# - not something I'd recommend...)

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out answer.  I was just trying to see if C# was capable of such low level memory management.   Basically what you're saying is that type of indexing cannot be done?  I can't get anything to work even using the fixed context.  Do you know if we are completely stuck using Int32, is that even a native type or an abstraction?

Comment: @Joshua: I edited my answer to show you how you can actually do it - but I really don't recommend it

Comment: On the platforms C# runs on, System.Int32 is the native int type. But under the hood int[] is the same block of memory you see in C++. If you do `test[5]`, under the hood the CLR will be doing a bounds check followed by pointer arithmetic and a dereference. You're not losing any low level manipulation in this case.

Comment: I agree, you must change the way you think and write in C# (compare with the c++), especial the pointer way. (+1)

Comment: I retracted my downvote. At the time I voted, your answer was only your first paragraph which I felt did not answer the question. But you completely turned around the answer into a very thorough explanation of the solution, with a side of why it shouldn't be done. That's how answers should be.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pin the array using the `fixed` keyword so it won't get moved by the GC:

```
fixed (int* test = new int[10])
{
    // ...
}
```

However, unsafe code in C# is more the exception than the rule. I'd try to translate your C code to non-unsafe C# code.

Comment: Note: Using fixed on variables should not be done with out a good reason as it makes the job for the GC harder... and you can run out of memory even if you don't use all the memory (memory defragmentation)..

Answer (score -4):

You need to learn the C# language.  Although there are syntactic similarities to C/C++, it - like Java - has a very different approach.

In C#, objects behave, by default, as references.  That is, you don't have to specify pointer referencing (&) and dereferencing (*) syntax.