# C# - return type int* from unmanaged code

Tags: c#, arrays, api, unmanaged

I am programming a small application to talk with an external device via API (both in 64bit). I got the following method from the guide I am trying to use:

```
int* GetRevision( void* cu_ptr, int num)
```

I tried to do `PinVoke` Pattern:

```
[DllImport("ABCAPI.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetRevision(IntPtr cu_ptr, int num);
```

And I tried to copy the `IntPtr` to an int array:

```
var check = GetRevision(device_cu_ptr, 1);
int[] arr = new int[10];  
Marshal.Copy(check, arr, 0, arr.Length);
```

Is there a better way to convert an `INT*` to `Int[]` in c#? Or could there be an mistake in my code?

Comment: Your last sentence hints towards the fact that this code isn't working. If that is so, can you explain exactly why it isn't?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointers in C# to make int array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546706/pointers-in-c-sharp-to-make-int-array)

Comment: @PaulZahra: Found that one too, but no, not a dupe. That's primarily about the misunderstanding, not how to fix it.

Comment: you are returning a pointer to an int, not an int itself. read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699534/how-to-convert-int-to-int

Comment: @jbutler483: That's about c, not c#.

Comment: Seems as though Marshal.Copy is the right way to go about it... see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146635%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: The problem is: I dont even know if the data i become from that array is still the revision number i want to have.

Comment: How do you expect *us* to know if you don't know?  Pick up the phone and call the programmer that worked on the C code.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i have a problem to explain my problem.

I only wanted to know that this code is without any "typecast error" or something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems like Marshal.Copy ist the right way to Convert those data types.

```
var check = GetRevision(device_cu_ptr, 1);
int[] arr = new int[10];  
Marshal.Copy(check, arr, 0, arr.Length);
```